# How to get the video not-mirrored when Skype video chat?

Tags: video, skype, mirroring

I work with my team using Skype and view their whiteboard but all text are mirrored. How can I get it fixed?

Comment: This works in Ubuntu 18: https://askubuntu.com/a/796328/769781

Answer (score 6):

Here's a way I eventually found that works.

It's independent of camera drivers or manufacturer, to a large extent.

The idea is to use software that takes input from the webcam, applies some transformations and then offers the output as a **virtual webcam**.

A virtual webcam is something that exists purely in software, but programs (which query the DirectShow API on Windows) see it in the list of installed webcams and can interact with it just as they would with a physical webcam.

I found an open-source program that provided the necessary functionality for me: [Webcamoid](https://webcamoid.github.io/).

How to use it is self-explanatory, except that to get the mirroring transformation, choose the filter called "Matrix Transformation" and specify a matrix like:

```
-0.75    0    0
0        1    0
```

(For some reason, to get the scaling right, I had to use "-0.75", but on some systems it would probably be just "-1".)

For a flip around the other axis, i.e. to fix it if the video is upside-down, change the "1" in the second row to "-1".

And it works: after enabling the virtual webcam in Webcamoid and restarting Skype, we see the virtual webcam in the list of webcams under Skype's `Options > Video`.

Webcamoid has to be kept running for this to work.

The downside is that this isn't a set-and-forget solution: one has to launch Webcamoid and set up the filter before every Skype session.

---

#### Miscellaneous notes

(Actually, for me this didn't work the first time. I had to restart Webcamoid and Skype a couple of times, tear down the virtual webcam and set it up again. But after this minimal settling in, it works well. Also, after certain combination of actions with its interface, Webcamoid crashes, but I just avoid taking those actions. When it runs steadily in the background, it seems to be quite stable and reliable.)

Another open-source program that seems to be able to solve the problem, using a similar approach, is [ucanvcam](http://classic.makesweet.com/webcam/ucanvcam/). However, when I start it up, it immediately crashes on my computer and I haven't investigated why. But maybe the bugs would be fixed by the time you read this.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to mention [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com), which seems to be free and open source. Worked pretty well for me to mirror webcam video, add overlays etc.

Note that OBS Studio's main purpose is to stream to video services such as twitch or YouTube. To use it in Skype, you need to install the [OBS-Virtualcam plugin](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/obs-virtualcam.539), which will give you a virtual webcam. The plugin description says that this works only in the Skype desktop app.

Answer (score 1):

Easy,go to Tools/Options...
Video Settings/WebCam Settings Image Mirror Flip :D

Comment: It seems to depend on the webcam device we use. Mine doesn't have the `Image Mirror Flip` option at all.

Comment: Strange, what do you see in Webcam Settings then?

Comment: The "Webcam settings" button brings up a device-dependent dialog: a different one is provided by each manufacturer. For example, on one computer I see a Logitech-branded window, with "Image orientation: ⨀ Normal  ⃝ Mirrored". On another computer I see a completely differently looking window entitled "Video Capture Filter Properties" with a tab called "Video Proc Amp" and nowhere to fix the mirroring that it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

**UWP**

When you are using the UWP version of Skype you will not get the Webcam properties option for most cameras:

[image: Chicony USB Camera UWP version]

**Desktop Version**

When you install the desktop version of Skype you get the properties to set underneath:

[image]

In these settings however there is no option to mirror the image for e.g. Chicony

[image]

But there is for Logitech:

[image]

So it is driver/manufacturer dependent. So this means you will have to search the internet or specify in the question the specific model. For each specific model there are threads over the internet of workarounds and sometimes the option to download different drivers to obtain the same functionality WITH mirroring.

Another generic option is to install another driver/application e..g ManyCam and choose this in the settings pulldown above the camera preview instead of your other driver. This will give you new options to manipulate the output.

[image]