# How to flip video feed that's presented upside down?

Tags: windows-7, skype, webcam

Skype an other applications running under windows 7 Ultimate are presenting the video captured from the laptop built-in webcam upside down.

I've tried many solution that I was able to find regarding issues like this, but to no avail. Some of the most relevant are discussed here:

- From Skype Support Network, the thread [why is my video image of myself upside-down???](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows/why-is-my-video-image-of-myself-upside-down/td-p/250680)
- From ASUSTek Forums, the thread [Built-in camera upside down](http://vip.asus.com/forum/view.aspx?board_id=3&model=W7J&id=20070912152106953&page=1&SLanguage=en-us)

Both present several potential solutions to this issue, but I've been unable to fix it for the laptop ASUS U6S.

### What I've already tried:

1. Changing Drivers

   The driver that works must be the one from Windows, all others available from [ASUS drivers](http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=U6S&p=3&s=107&os=24&hashedid=xmPmUSMmopetlfgO) either don't install or install but the webcam doesn't provide any video feed. This disallows all options that concern using an older driver or editing the `.inf` file as to manually adjust the settings.

   <sup>ASUS does not provide drivers for Windows 7, so I've used drivers from Windows Vista 32 Bit.</sup>
2. Using the application [manycam](http://www.manycam.com/)

   This application actually solves the issue (temporarily), but creates new ones:

   - If I use the application to flip the video feed, Skype video call cease to work.
   - This application doesn't save the settings, at least I wasn't able to find any way to save the settings I've used to flip the video feed.

   <sup>A computer restart brings all back to how it was, video feed upside down and if the application is still installed, Skype continues to fail on video calls.</sup>
3. Regedit

   I've searched thru Windows Registry Editor as to find any reference to the webcam settings, hopping to find a key with the `Flip` parameter, since it's up to the driver to flip the image (by what I could ascertain from this problem).

   <sup>Couldn't find any reference to such settings, either they actually don't exist within the Windows Registry or they use some weird name that I could think off.</sup>
4. System Configuration

   I was able to access the webcam system settings from the Windows Device Manager, but the tab that actually has the Image Rotation setting is always disabled.

   The same goes for the settings available from the Skype webcam options (that essentially is presenting the same settings as Windows Device Manager, just within a custom Skype pop-up).

### Question:

How can I flip the video feed from the laptop's built-in webcam, as to properly see and broadcast the video?

Comment: I assume holding the laptop upside down is not an option :).

Comment: @BradPatton Dang, that was my idea.

Comment: [Here's a solution](https://superuser.com/a/1256781/141883) for the related problem where the webcam is mirrored instead of upside-down. But the fix is similar, see the link. It uses the open-source program [Webcamoid](https://webcamoid.github.io/) instead of Manycam. Skype video call works, but the inconvenience of having to set it up all over again every time is still there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two threads full of solutions that worked for some people.

The funniest remark was that it is not a driver issue but an Asus one,
because the camera is really physically installed upside-down.
So one solution is to find a technician that can flip your camera.
Or if the computer is under warranty, demand it of your vendor.

[**How to Fix the Problem of ASUS Upside Down Webcam**](http://www.asus-drivers.com/resources/how-to-solve-webcam-upside-down-issue.html)

Solutions in this thread:

1. Modify WebCam setting, if the software allows it
2. Download a Webcam Driver from the ASUS support site corresponding to your hardware PID
3. Update Webcam Driver with Driver Detective
4. Edit registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Sunplus SPUVCb\VIDEOPROCAMP`,
   set VFlip value to 1.

[**Built-in camera upside down**](http://vip.asus.com/forum/view.aspx?board_id=3&model=W7J&id=20070912152106953&page=1&SLanguage=en-us)

Solutions in this thread:

1) adjust the settings

> Run the camera through the Windows Explorer. Your camera built-in will
>   appear upside down, right? 
> Inside the folder with the drivers provided
>   by ASUS there´s a software called tsnp2std.exe. 
> With your camera
>   opened, run this application; you will notice a small icon in tray
>   area; right click on it and now choose the option: Open Property Page.
>   
> Well, now you should not have problem to setup and adjust the
>   settings.

2) Reinstall driver with flip

> I resolved it by editing the snp2uvc.inf file. Open it with notepad
>   and search for the word "flip". You'll see entries like this:
>   `HKR,DefaultSettings,Flip,0x00010001,0` and `HKR,Settings,Flip,0x00010001,0`.
>   Change the last digit (zero) to a "1"
>   to all instances. Save the file and re-install your drivers manually
>   from Device Manager. Choose the driver to install, do not let Windows
>   search for you. 
> Reboot and your video will be in the correct
>   orientation.

3) Roll-back the driver to the original one that came with the computer

Comment: After reading the aditional information from your answer, I started to test even older drivers from Asus. I've been successful solving this problem, by using the **MVI-SV1103-AD Camera Driver for Vista from 2007.10.25**, available from an Asus model search with this [parameters](http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=U6S&p=3&s=107&os=24&hashedid=xmPmUSMmopetlfgO).

Comment: After installed, I didn't had to change any settings at all, all was OK. Thank you for the additional help on this matter. *(If you wish, add this driver reference and the link I've provided to your answer, as to have it with the solution that definitely solved this question.)*

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and tried many many ways. 
I found a simple way to solve it yesterday, very accidental! 
I was trying SKYPE for windows, after installation, the camera was upside down as I anticipated. BUT . . . there was a button inside the SKYPE to flip the camera!!! 
That solved the whole problem! I am excited . . .

Comment: Please provide a canonical source which describes the Skype 'inversion' button, or grab a screenshot. Click [edit] to add either to your answer.